# Bind9 and Web Server on the same machine + domain setup

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, lamp

I want to ask can I setup for example **LAMP** with all domains and **Bind9** on the same machine ?

If yes, ok.

Now I have one **.com** domain for example : **site.com**

Now I want to understand the steps to do to have in the end this:

**ns1.site.com**

**ns2.site.com**

In particularly I need yours help to understand a logic to setup all this software.

Thanks

Comment: sorry we will not provide any learning material. yes it is possible to run a Webserver and a Nameserver on the same Maschine. But you will need regardless a second one for the second ns.

Comment: I can do it without second ? Put in the second same ip ? Or make a second public DNS ?

Comment: I would suggest that you take a look at manuals and some howto. even if you want to force this behavior, when you're got a outage all is offline and unreachable. Due the state of question it's offtopic on serverfault.com